# How can I submit a job form Zeppelin as a specific user?

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I am running Zeppelin on my cluster with user accounts set up, and I can log in to Zeppelin with my credentials, but all jobs submitted by all users show as being submitted by the user 'zeppelin'.

Is there a way to have Zeppelin submit jobs to the cluster from a specific user, instead of the 'zeppelin' user?

Answer (score 1):

Running a Zeppelin interpreter process as the user logged in to the Zeppelin frontend is called *user impersonation*. 
The steps to enable user impersonation are documented in the user manual: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/manual/userimpersonation.html

In a nutshell, you have to

1. Enable authentication in conf/shiro.ini
2. Enable password-less ssh
3. Configure the interpreter to impersonate the user